# Objective C- BLE device Manufacturers data comparison

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a task of comparing Manufacturers data to a string to display the BLE devices .

```
-(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *):didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    NSString *manufac=[advertisementData objectForKey:CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey];
    NSString *string=@"57394423 4334445 55";
    if([string isEqualToString:manufac])
       NSLog(@"yes it is the device");
    else
       NSLog(@"sorry not a device");
}
```

'manufac' when printed gives result as <57394423 4334445 55> which doesnot prove to be correct at any time.
How can it be compared ? please help.

Comment: Hey, that you want to find out this comparison? (NSLog(@"yes it is the device");) May be u should look at UUID?

Comment: yes the 'If condition' and get it print either "yes it is the device" and  if no "sorry not a device"

Comment: what does it mean (yes it is the device) ? may be u should compare device UUID, instead of manufac?

Comment: The UUID is generated locally by iOS and tells you nothing about the discovered device.

Comment: id?It's a reserved word,you can't use it!

Comment: `<57394423 4334445 55>`, seems to be `NSData` to me, not `NSString`. `[[advertisementData objectForKey:CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey] class]` is `NSString` or `NSData`?

Answer (score 0):

The object returned by the `CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey` is an `NSData` object.
You are assigning it to an `NSString` object which is wrong.

To get the UUID you could do the following:

```
NSData *manufacturer = [advertisementData objectForKey:CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey];
NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDBytes:manufacturer.bytes];
```

And then compare this UUID to the one you are searching for. If you need an actual `NSString` representation, use `uuid.UUIDString`.