# Get Manufacturer Data from BLE on iOS devices

Tags: ios, xamarin

In my Xamarin.Android app, I can read Manufacturer Data from BLE with the following code:

```
public class CustomScanCallback : ScanCallback
{
    public override void OnScanResult([GeneratedEnum] ScanCallbackType callbackType, ScanResult result)
    {
        base.OnScanResult(callbackType, result);

        if (result.ScanRecord.ManufacturerSpecificData != null)
        {
            var dataByteResult = result.ScanRecord.GetManufacturerSpecificData(0xFFFE);

            if (dataByteResult != null)
            {
                Guid dataResult = new Guid(dataByteResult);

                if (dataResult.ToString() == "myUuid")
                {
                    // found the uuid from my UWP app
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do the same on Xamarin.iOS? I have a callback for when peripherals are discovered:

```
_cbCentralManager.DiscoveredPeripheral += CBCentralManager_DiscoveredPeripheral;

private void CBCentralManager_DiscoveredPeripheral(object sender, CBDiscoveredPeripheralEventArgs e)
{
    // how to find "myUuid" ?
}
```

And have tried many things to find it, but couldn't. An answer in Swift/Obective-C would help too as I can translate it to C#.

**EDIT**

I looked through the advertisement data parameter with the key `CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey` and found the value:

`<06000109 2002aa4e 7e54b91f 2212c398 74eb0fe9 9fc3ecce 4ce76d8f aa>`

It looks like it's encoded in hex format, but don't think it's my uuid that I am looking for...

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerdelegate/1518937-centralmanager?language=objc should be called. Then, in the `advertisementData` dictionary parameter, should might have a key (`CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey`)/value for the manufacturer. I don't remember if the value is of type `NSString` or `NSData`, but you should get it.

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: Look through this link. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerdelegate/advertisement_data_retrieval_keys?language=objc Have you tried `CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey` ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbadvertisementdatamanufacturerdatakey?language=objc If you look here it is NSData, so you'd need to create the NSData object and then create a string from it.

Comment: It's not in the `CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey`, I checked it. The app that I'm reading it from put the uuid in the manufacturer data as a string. I know becuase I can read on my Android app by calling `GetManufacturerSpecificData`

Comment: You may please checkout following link it might be helpful for you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22837799/4843725 or if it does not works then checkout this one. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35059094/4843725

Comment: I read through those posts, and what I understood from them is that it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Hex code is the `NSData` which you can see it is from [these](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbadvertisementdatamanufacturerdatakey?language=objc) docs. To get that into a string I would use the following.

```
     NSData data = NSData.FromData(theValueFromDictionary);
     string uuidString = data.ToString();
     //Try this if the other line doesn't work. But string encoding should be UTF-16 (the default) or UTF-8
     //string uuidString = data.ToString(NSStringEncoding.UTF8);
```

If that isn't your desired string then you could play around with the type of encoding you are using, but in my experience apple usually goes between data and strings with `UTF-8`.

Perhaps the UUID is another key in this dictionary. Take a look a look at all the available keys [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerdelegate/advertisement_data_retrieval_keys?language=objc)

Comment: `data.ToString()` returns the same string in hex format. `data.ToString(NSStringEncoding.UTF8)` throws an exception

Comment: Have you taken a look at any of the other keys?

Comment: Yes I searched through all of them. In my Android implementation, I'm looking in `0xFFFE` as a key, not sure how to do that in iOS..

Answer (score 0):

You can get the manufacturer info in the advertisementData.
Following this code .

```
#pragma mark - CBCentralManagerDelegate
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {
    NSString *manufacturer = [advertisementData objectForKey:CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey];
    NSLog(@"manufacturer:%@", manufacturer); 
}
```